# How to implement custom internationalization with gwt?

Tags: gwt, internationalization

I want to make custom internationalization for my gwt app. What does this means? Imagine that my app must be internationalized for men and women. (id=men, id=women).
is it possible to make two different .properties files like 
MyAppMessages_men_en.properties
MyAppMessages_women_en.properties

MyAppMessages_men_fr.properties
MyAppMessages_men_fr.properties

etc...

and my app host page will be accessed like this for example http://blabla/MyAppHostPage.html?locale=en&id=men 
and this must load english version for men.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using fictional locale identifiers such as `en_US_Men` and `en_US_Women` and so forth for other locales?
(note that you *should* include a country whenever you include a variant of a locale)

Otherwise, I'd suggest using an abstract factory for your Messages and switch the concrete implementation using deferred binding on a distinct property (men vs. women):

```java
interface MyAppMessagesFactory { MyAppMessages create(); }

class MyAppMessagesFactory_Men implements MyAppMessagesFactory {
   @Override
   public MyAppMessages create() { return GWT.create(MyAppMessages_Men.class); }
}


class MyAppMessagesFactory_Women implements MyAppMessagesFactory {
   @Override
   public MyAppMessages create() { return GWT.create(MyAppMessages_Women.class); }
}
```

You'd then have your MyAppMessages_Men_en.properties and MyAppMessages_Women_en.properties.

Comment: Yes, i wan to use en_US_Men and en_US_Women, but how will my gwt app understand what it has to user en_US_Men when i access it like this:
http://blabla/MyApp.html?locale=en_US&id=Men
This way i request my app to use locale en_US and id=Men, so i want to use en_US_Men. It is also not a problem to use locale=en_US_Men (pass as one param). Do i have to do something with differed binging?

Comment: If you use `locale=en_US_Men` you shouldn't have nothing else to change. Otherwise, you'd have to provide your own `property-provider` for the `locale` property (that'd read both query-string arguments and concatenate them to form the property's value)

Comment: Hi I tried this. I created two properties files MyMessages_en_US_Women.properties and MyMessages_en_US_Men.properties

I added in myApp.gwt.xml:
   <extend-property name="locale" values="en_US_Men"/>
   <extend-property name="locale" values="en_US_Women"/>

and when i hit the host page with &locale=en_US_Men
i get an error saying "No resource found for key ...."

If i change the names of the properties files to 
MyMessages_enUSMen.properties
and 
<extend-property name="locale" values="enUSMen"/>
and use locale=enUSMen (analogically for Women) everything works.